# How does the NSA "masquerade as any routable IPv4 or IPv6 host"?

Tags: spoofing, ip-spoofing, nsa

I was reading the Wikipedia article about [TAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailored_Access_Operations) and there is written that:

> Details on a program titled QUANTUMSQUIRREL indicate NSA ability to masquerade as any routable IPv4 or IPv6 host. This enables an NSA computer to generate false geographical location and personal identification credentials when accessing the Internet utilizing QUANTUMSQUIRREL.

I know that of course is possible to spoof the IP address of a packet. That is, to send out a packet with a fake "sender" IP address. But then the answer by the server should arrive to the "sender" IP address it sees, not the "real" one.

1. How, from a technical point of view, can the NSA act as an arbitrary IP address, meaning they can send *and receive* packets from and *to* and IP address?

   What is the computer science technique they are using?
2. When they open the terminal, what are the commands they type? What third party utilities they are using?
3. Would the NSA require cooperation from other parties to achieve this?

Comment: They may be doing this at the BGP layer.  See https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2018/10/chinas_hacking_.html.

Comment: @user253751I mean, at a deeper level than that, but not so deep as to Kernel calls. Let's say what third-party user-space software they use

Comment: @user253751 I have clarified my questions

Comment: @raffaem well it's probably first-party software. You think someone *else* has made software to intercept traffic to arbitrary IP addresses?

Comment: @user253751 I think there may be some `echo "New route: A.B.C.D to E.F.G.H" > /dev/tcp/BGP_SERVER_IP/BGP_SERVER_PORT` that changes the routes

Comment: @user253751 I'm wondering how they are using third-party softwares to do that. I don't think they built an entire operating system from scratch. They must be using linux or something, possibly with its built-in commands

Comment: @raffaem I bet they send a command to their interception system that is capable of intercepting anything from anywhere. And that calculates which network links are likely to receive those packets, and sends a command to the interception devices on that particular network links to capture them. And those interception devices use DPDK or even custom hardware to read the packets really fast and filter them. That's just a guess though. You can't do it unless you're the NSA.

Comment: I googled "QUANTUMSQUIRREL" and got this result: https://theintercept.com/document/2014/03/12/nsa-gchqs-quantumtheory-hacking-tactics/ It appears to be part of the QUANTUM INSERT functions. They simply infect a victim browser and use that as a pivot point